# I'm writing a code in Java, but when I compile, the Error: “java uses or overrides a deprecated API.” comes up

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The prompt for the code I am writing is:

This assignment involves writing a program that models a super hero. A super hero has a name, wears a special suit when performing hero duties, might wear a cape, and has a birth date. A super hero is also able to invoke his/her special powers when called on to do so.

Implement a class named SuperHero that models the above description. Use a Name class to represent the name attribute, and a Date class to represent the birth date attribute. You may use the Date class from the lectures or define your own. If the super hero is wearing their special suit, then the suit attribute should indicate this. Similarly, if the super hero is wearing a cape, then a cape attribute should indicate this. String types can be used for these two attributes. There should also be an attribute that indicates whether the super hero is invoking their special powers, and a method to set and unset the special powers attribute. Provide appropriate class constructors, getter methods, setter methods, and any other methods you think are necessary to model a super hero.

Write a main method that creates an array of SuperHero objects and displays their attributes and displays whether their super powers are being invoked.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Name
{
  String name;

  public String Name() //Name(String name)
  {
    this.name=name;
    return this.name;
  }

  public String getName()
  {

    return name;
  }
}

public class SuperHero 
{
  String cape,suit,specialPowers,name,dob;

  public static void main(String args[])

  {

    int insuper=0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many superheros would you like");

    insuper = sc.nextInt();

    SuperHero[] sh=new SuperHero[insuper];

    for(int i=0;i<insuper;i++)

    {

      System.out.println("Specify features to the Super Hero "+(i+1)+" That you want for them" );

      System.out.println("Name : ");

      Name n=new Name(sc.next());

      sh[i].name=n.getName();

      System.out.println("Date of Birth");

      Date dd = new Date(sc.next());

      sh[i].dob=dd.toString();

      System.out.println("will he have a cape: (y/n)");

      String ch=sc.next();

      if (ch.charAt(0) == 'y' || ch.charAt(0) == 'Y') 

        sh[i].cape = "yes";

      else 

        sh[i].cape = "no";


      System.out.println("Will he have a suit: (y/n)");

      ch=sc.next();

      if(ch.charAt(0) == 'y' || ch.charAt(0) == 'Y')

        sh[i].suit = "yes";

      else

        sh[i].suit = "no";

      System.out.println("Will he have super powers (y/n)");

      ch=sc.next();

      if(ch.charAt(0) == 'y' || ch.charAt(0) == 'Y')
      {
        sh[i].seSuperPowers();
      }

      else
        sh[i].unSetSuperPowers();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<insuper;i++)

    {

      System.out.println("Super man "+(i+1)+" consist of these features");

      System.out.println("Name : "+sh[i].name);

      System.out.println("Date of birth : "+sh[i].dob);

      System.out.println("Suit : "+sh[i].cape);

      System.out.println("Powers : "+sh[i].getSuperPowers());

    }

  }


  void seSuperPowers()
  {
    specialPowers = "yes";
  }


  void unSetSuperPowers()
  {
    specialPowers = "no";
  }


  String getSuperPowers()
  {
    return specialPowers;
  }

}
```

Whenever I compile, this error comes up:

```
    Note: SuperHero.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
    Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Could anyone please help me, re-write or edit the code, it will be much appreciated?

Comment: `public String Name()` what is this? a constructor that returns a string?

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Your `Name` class doesn't have a constructor (other than the default). A constructor does not have a return type and doesn't return anything. It has a *method* (not a constructor) whose name is `Name`, but that is just confusing, it's not a constructor. Why did you comment out the `Name( String name)` part? That is the correct constructor definition.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
public String Name() //Name(String name)
      {
        this.name=name;
        return this.name;
      }
```

is not at all what you think it is.

It is not a constructor. Constructors look like `public Name()` - note that it contains any number of modifiers (`public` is a modifier), then the name of the type, then parens. **It must not include a return type**. You just made a method named `Name` which returns a string.

Then,

`this.name = name` - is a no-op. It's the same as `this.name = this.name`. The only `name` variable in scope here is your field (and `this.name` also refers to that field).

What you want is:

```
public Name(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

note:

1. There is no return type, thus, it is a constructor.
2. It takes as argument a string, named `name` - this 'shadows' the field which is also named `name`.
3. `this.name = name;` now does something: `name` by itself refers to that parameter, `this.name` refers to the field. Thus, this statement says: Take the parameter, assign it to the `name` field.
4. There is no `return` statement. Other than just `return;`, return statements are not allowed in constructors.

Comment: thank you @rzwitserloot, however, now it is showing another compile error similar to that already in the post.                                                                                                              the Error states:                                                                                                               
        Note: SuperHero.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.                                              
        Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details

Comment: You changed the question. This new thing is a warning and entirely unrelated. Open up a new question on SO and edit this one back to the original, as now the answer (as well as that error) no longer make sense. Whenever your compiler complains, always include the full error - including the line number, because that is rather crucial info of course. We'd need to be able to match the line the compiler is complaining about with the line in your snippet.